# DateTime.TryParseExact constantly returns false

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have the following code which takes the element in the lines array and checks if it matches the datetime format. This check only runs on elements 37, 38, 40, 41. Given the following code and debugging print outs I can see that the output does match the parsing. Why does it return false then?

Possible Inputs:

```
05/03/2005 23:59:59.999
05/3/2005 23:59:59.999
5/03/2005 23:59:59.999
5/3/2005 23:59:59.999
etc...
```

**Code:**

```
lines[i] = lines[i] + " 23:59:59.999"; //YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]
DateTime datetest;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(lines[i], "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out datetest))
{
}
else
{
    //Log and Drop
    logfile.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss") + ": Row #" + row + ", Column #" + (i) + " was not a date in the right format, dropping line. ");
    logfile.WriteLine("Original: " + lines[i]);
    Console.WriteLine("Date Wrong");
    Console.WriteLine("Date: " + lines[i]);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    continue;

}
```

**Console Output:**

```
Date Wrong
Date: 5/23/2004 23:59:59.999
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried changing the parse to look for M/dd/yyyy instead. However I now get this output instead.

```
Date Wrong
Date: 05/23/2005 23:59:59.999
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok I tried changing the parse to look for "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff" as many suggested. The output I get now is:

```
Date Wrong
Date: 23.59.59.999
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Ok I have now tried "M/d/y H:m:s.fff" as suggested and I am still getting output as:

```
Date Wrong
Date: 05/23/2005 23:59:59.999
```

Comment: MM means month with leading zero, maybe you want M?

Comment: .mmm is not correct, use .fff

Comment: I do want to account for leading 0's as they are possible. Could it be possible to do a [M]M. I doubt it

Comment: Ok I tried that, check my edited question.

Comment: Based on your last edit (update 2), one of your inputs is an empty string. I think it's understandable that it won't be parsed by your method.

Comment: That's true, I have no idea why that one only with that parse came up as empty string...I will investigate that element further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** Answer based on original revision of the question before it started morphing.

> Why does it return false then?

The `MM` format requires two digits for the month. Your date string only has one digit. Use the `M` month format. The milliseconds format string should be `fff` rather than `mmm`.

The following format string will parse your input

```
M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff
```

To demonstrate:

```
DateTime datetest;
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParseExact("5/23/2004 23:59:59.999", 
    "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out datetest));
```

which outputs

```
True
```

If you wish to allow for single digit months then you need `d` instead of `dd`. In order for you to proceed much further, you will need to work out exactly what format of dates you wish to support.

Comment: I do want to account for leading 0's as they are possible. Could it be possible to do a [M]M. I doubt it

Comment: You can use `M`, like I said. That will also cater for leading `0` month digits. You'll also need to use `d` for the day, and so on

Comment: Ya I tried that and tried doing a single d instead of dd but it gets caught when I hit something with a leading 0.

Comment: Please read your question again. You asked why the code in the question failed.

Comment: That is true, but I am trying to find something that works because it currently still fails.

Comment: No it does not!! The input in the question works with the changes I propose. Do you really expect us to handle input data that is not in the question?

Comment: I've added sample possible inputs to my question. I've added sample input to my question, there is no need to get angry David.

Comment: You are wasting our time. You asked a simple question which we answered. Then you changed the question. Please revert the question to its original form and accept one of the answers. Then spend some time working out what you really want to ask, and ask that.

Comment: I would consider doing that, but an answer was not necessarily given as so far nothing has worked. If something was provided that was proven to have been the cause of the false boolean than I would be more than happy to accept it. But, nothing has worked as of yet, so from what I can see there is no way of knowing what was truly the problem in the first place.

Comment: Now that worked, thank you for editing your question after my last comment to include the working code. I will be happy to accept your answer as you have shown what was wrong and what was needed to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong datetime format that you try to parse to. Change it to: "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"

In response to the comment:

```
DateTime datetest;
var dateTimes = new [] { "05/03/2005 23:59:59.999", "05/3/2005 23:59:59.999", "5/03/2005 23:59:59.999", "5/3/2005 23:59:59.999" };

foreach(var dateTimeToParse in dateTimes)
    if (DateTime.TryParse("5/3/2005 23:59:59.999", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out datetest))
        Console.WriteLine(dateTimeToParse + " parses to: " + datetest);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("FAIL!");
```

Works on my machine:

05/03/2005 23:59:59.999 parses to: 2005-05-03 23:59:59

05/3/2005 23:59:59.999 parses to: 2005-05-03 23:59:59

5/03/2005 23:59:59.999 parses to: 2005-05-03 23:59:59

5/3/2005 23:59:59.999 parses to: 2005-05-03 23:59:59

Comment: Ya I tried that but it gets caught when I hit something with a leading 0.

Comment: @Kyle See the trailing .fff instead of your .mmm

Comment: @Kyle Well then don't use ParseExact!

Comment: Fair enough, what would you suggest that allows for defining some kind of schema?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the contents of lines[I], but the mismatch between the format described in the comment and the format used in the TryParse may just be your issue:

```
lines[i] = lines[i] + " 23:59:59.999"; //YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]
...
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(lines[i], "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm",
```

Comment: I do want to account for leading 0's as they are possible. Could it be possible to do a [M]M. I doubt it

Answer (score 1):

Using this (like already suggested Hans and David):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> datetimeList = new List<string>();
        datetimeList.Add("05/03/2005 23:59:59.999");
        datetimeList.Add("05/3/2005 23:59:59.999");
        datetimeList.Add("5/03/2005 23:59:59.999");
        datetimeList.Add("5/3/2005 23:59:59.999");
        DateTime datetest;
        foreach (string s in datetimeList)
        {
            if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out datetest))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

prints 4 times "Success" .

This only a proof of concept, i don't want any upvotes.

Comment: What an interesting approach, and successful for that sample data. But those were just examples, if my date was in those formats but with unknown values. Something like */*/* 23:59:59.999 this obviously wouldn't work. Is there a way to account for these wildcards?

Comment: wildcards what for ? As a date to guess ? How should this work ?

Comment: Wildcards? Are you having a joke at our expense!!?! For the love of God, ask a question and stick to it. Please stop changing your mind as to what you are asking. I urge you to revert the question to the original form.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Don't you have a crystallball at your hands ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not changing the question, it was a simple question based off this answer. I agree it works but only with the sample data. It was a question to find out if this solution could be adapted to account for other numbers when they aren't known. I'm sorry you feel I'm wasting your time but you don't have to be rude. Nothing is stopping you from leaving, its not like you're tied here. I'm not breaking the rules here. I am posting follow up questions since the original question was not answered and I thought the "Updates" would maybe help us all get to the bottom of the problem.